# How to display custom DataTable filters that align with each other?

Tags: jquery, razor, datatables, bootstrap-4

I'm having trouble understanding how to display custom filters that will align with the default DataTable filters. From my understanding, the html of the DataTable gets built on the fly via Javascript. I have a custom `@Html.DropDownList` that I want to put to the left of the search box, but not sure how to do this since I don't have the Datatable HTML to work with. How can I have the "Show Entries" "Search" and my custom @Html.DropDownList show on the same row? I have also attached a screenshot to give a better visual. [image]

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Report_Completion_Status"))
                            {
                                @Html.DropDownList("SelectedReportCategory", new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Report_Category"], "ReportCategoryID", "ReportCategory"), "All", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "this.form.submit();", style = "width: 300px" })
                            }
                        </div>
                        <table class="table table-striped dom-jQuery-events table-xs table-hover" id="table_id" style="border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="padding-left: 5px">
                                        Name
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        Popularity
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        Change Log
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                  <td>
                                  </td>
                                   <td>
                                  </td>
                                   <td>
                                  </td>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Comment: You need to create a custom layout via the `dom` option: https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom#Examples

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DataTables `dom` option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom), and then add the HTML for the dropdown select using one of the DataTables events, for example the `draw` event...

Put the length control (`l`) and search filter (`f`) in a flexbox row at the before the table (`t`) renders...

```
dom: '<"d-flex w-100"<l><"#mydiv.d-flex ml-auto text-right"f>>tips',
```

Once the table `draw` event occurs, prepend the HTML to "#mydiv"...

```
var customFilter = "(HTML for dropdown here)";
table.on('draw', function () {
    customFilter.prependTo('#mydiv');
});
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/TjyjZT36yb

Comment: Thanks Zim for your solution. Working on this now. I will update once I have it running.

Comment: I used your example in my project. I replaced the selectString with my Html.DropdownList and it did not seem to like that syntax. Can I incorporate Html helpers using the dom options?